# can sombody explain diffrence between SqlConnectionOwnership.Internal vs SqlConnectionOwnership.External

Tags: c#

I am new to ADO.Net.

I have this code ?

```
 SqlDataReader dataReader = null;
            var mustCloseConnection = false;
            var cmd = new SqlCommand();
            try
            {
                PrepareCommand(cmd, connection, transaction, commandType, commandText, commandParameters, out mustCloseConnection);
                if(connectionOwnership ==SqlConnectionOwnership.Internal)
                {
                    dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
                else
                {
                    dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                }
                var canClear = true;
                foreach (SqlParameter commandParameter in cmd.Parameters)
                {
                    if (commandParameter.Direction != ParameterDirection.Input)
                        canClear = false;
                }
                if (canClear)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                }
                return dataReader;
            }
            catch
            {
                if (mustCloseConnection)
                    connection.Close();
                throw;
            }
```

Can somebody explain ?

```
if(connectionOwnership ==SqlConnectionOwnership.Internal)
                {
                    dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
                else
                {
                    dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                }
```

I know SqlConnectionOwnership for pooling.

Any luck ?

Comment: *"I know SqlConnectionOwnership for pooling."*. I don't think you do know that, given that it doesn't appear that it is used for that purpose.

Comment: @jmcilhinney can you explain what internal vs external mean ?

Comment: You mean like I already did in the answer I posted over 24 hours ago? If you post a question, don't post a comment asking someone to answer the question. If they've got an answer, the question is already enough.

Answer (score 3):

That type does not appear to be part of .NET itself. Based on [this page](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/SqlConnectionOwnership/-/php-sqlconnectionownership-class-examples.html), people are creating their own helper libraries for ADO.NET code and the corresponding parameter is used to indicate whether the connection object was passed in by the calling code or created within the helper. This is the first example from that page:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Create and prepare a SqlCommand, and call ExecuteReader with the appropriate CommandBehavior.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// If we created and opened the connection, we want the connection to be closed when the DataReader is closed.
/// 
/// If the caller provided the connection, we want to leave it to them to manage.
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="connection">a valid SqlConnection, on which to execute this command</param>
/// <param name="transaction">a valid SqlTransaction, or 'null'</param>
/// <param name="commandType">the CommandType (stored procedure, text, etc.)</param>
/// <param name="commandText">the stored procedure name or T-SQL command</param>
/// <param name="commandParameters">an array of SqlParameters to be associated with the command or 'null' if no parameters are required</param>
/// <param name="connectionOwnership">indicates whether the connection parameter was provided by the caller, or created by SqlHelper</param>
/// <returns>SqlDataReader containing the results of the command</returns>
private static SqlDataReader ExecuteReader(SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction, CommandType commandType, string commandText, SqlParameter[] commandParameters, SqlConnectionOwnership connectionOwnership)
{
    //create a command and prepare it for execution
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    PrepareCommand(cmd, connection, transaction, commandType, commandText, commandParameters);

    //create a reader
    SqlDataReader dr;

    // call ExecuteReader with the appropriate CommandBehavior
    if (connectionOwnership == SqlConnectionOwnership.External)
    {
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
    else
    {
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    }

    // detach the SqlParameters from the command object, so they can be used again.
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();

    return dr;
}
```

Note the method documentation for the relevant parameter:

> indicates whether the connection parameter was provided by the caller, or created by SqlHelper

Presumably `External` means passed in by the calling code, so it is left up to that calling code to decide when to close the connection, which may be being used for other things. `Internal` would mean created by the helper, so the connection's only purpose is to be used for that data reader, so it is closed when the reader is closed.

Note that I have never heard of this type before and I found this information simply by searching the web.